# Postgresql starting error

Tags: server, postgresql

The postgresql 9.1 database server is not starting.

Can anyone help in this.

```
* Restarting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server                                     
* Removed stale pid file.
The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
2013-07-25 10:59:52 IST PANIC:  could not read from control file: Input/output error
                                                                         [fail]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Please post output of: `tail /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main.log`

Comment: `tail -n 50` would be good; the default line count from `tail` is often not sufficient.

Comment: we have ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: Here the error code from the log file                                                                                                                           2013-07-25 10:33:13 IST PANIC:  could not read from control file: Input/output error
2013-07-25 10:59:52 IST PANIC:  could not read from control file: Input/output error
2013-07-25 11:19:46 IST PANIC:  could not read from control file: Input/output error
2013-07-25 11:23:03 IST PANIC:  could not read from control file: Input/output error